# Mysql case issue

Tags: mysql

I'm creating a sql query by taking certain variables from the form field. But some areas repeat each other. So this breaks the MySQL case structure. To give an example:

```
(case 
  when `field` IN (1,2) then 'area 1'
  when `field` = 3 then 'area 2'
  when `field` = 4 then 'area 3'
  when `field` IN (1,2,3,4) then 'area 4'
end) as cases

Group by cases
```

I know 'area 4' will never show up in the results, but is there a way to show?

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9307b6/1)

Answer (score 0):

Order them by priorities. First the best match query then the smaller ones.

Like that:

```
(case 
  when `field` IN (1,2,3,4) then 'area 4'
  when `field` IN (1,2) then 'area 1'
  when `field` = 3 then 'area 2'
  when `field` = 4 then 'area 3'
end) as cases
```

Comment: But then I'm just getting the result of 'area 4'. I want to see all the cases

Comment: The link to sqlfiddle doesnt load

Answer (score 0):

In reference to your SQLfiddle

Below is the query that i could come up with

```
SELECT ROUND(SUM(quantity)/1000) as `quantity`,
ROUND(SUM(value)/1000) as `value`,
(case 
   when istpoz REGEXP '^(7207|7218|7224|7206)' 
   then
    case when istpoz REGEXP '^(7206|7207)' 
         then 'Yarı Mamul (Alaşımsız)'   else 'Yarı Mamul (Tamamı)'  end
    else
    case
      when istpoz REGEXP '^(7224)' then 'Yarı Mamul (Alaşımlı Çelik)' 
      when istpoz REGEXP '^(7218)' then 'Yarı Mamul (Paslanmaz Ç.)' 
    end
end) as istpozz,
`year` FROM 
export as x WHERE 
`year` IN (2016) 
AND `month` IN (1,2,3,4) 
AND `country_id` IN (1) 
AND `istpoz` REGEXP '^(7206|7207|7224|7218)' GROUP BY istpozz,year
```